# Adding an item to multiple lists at once

Tags: flutter, dart

Imagine you have two lists :
  - `list A`
  - `list B`

The `list A` contains multiple `list B`,
I want to be able to add an item to all `list B` that are contain in the `list A`  in one time.
I already make some research about it and i couldn't find any solution for my problem .
Thank you.

Comment: Please, show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise, it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help you to improve your question. Good luck!

Comment: What do you mean by multiple list B? You are saying that list B elements are there in list A?

Comment: @MuhammadNoman Yes list B elements are inside the list A, and my goal to add like a String to all list B that are contained inside the List A in one time

Comment: Means, you want to update that same string which is in both list A and list B? Right?

Comment: No, the list A contain multiple list B, all the list B are empty, i want to add a String to all list B in one time @MuhammadNoman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to iterate through the list and add the string you want to add.

```dart
List<List<String>> listA = [[], [], [], []]; // I'm assuming your list 
                                             // is something like this

listA.forEach((listB) {
  listB.add('String to be added');
});
```

Comment: Thank you  for you're help ^^